What enables sinners to ‘transfer’ from ‘being found in Adam’ to being ‘found in Christ’?
Having read an article in the British November 2024 Evangelical Times newspaper on this question, I was heartily in agreement with it till halfway through, thus giving rise to my question.
Very briefly, the writer clearly showed from scripture that we are all doomed to fall under God’s judgment unless our union with Adam changes to union with Christ (Romans 5:14). But then I was troubled to read an interpretation of that chapter claiming we are “saved through the obedience of Christ.” The writer subscribes to the Westminster Confession of Faith that this was Christ perfectly keeping the Law on our behalf. (XIX.5 & 6) Yet the writer then admitted that:

[Many Christians] “still find the pull of legalism to be powerful… Is
my Christian living up to standard? Am I doing well enough to remain
on track for heaven?” Evangelical Times, article ‘Joined to the wrong man’ p.10, Vol. 58 No.11

He says such questions are inapplicable as it is who we are united to that determines eternal destinies – and that is true – but my question is, What enables anyone to be transferred from being united to Adam to Christ? (I am not asking whether we are joined to Adam - this question is for those in the Reformed Protestant category, for whom that is a given.)
I thought Romans chapter 5 spoke of our “being justified by his blood… reconciled by the death of his Son… saved by his life” (vs. 9-10). When it speaks of obedience, it is Christ having been “obedient unto death, even the death of the cross”, surely?
Is there anywhere in the entire Bible that states we have union with Christ through his obedience to the Law? Yet if people believe that, is it no wonder they get pulled into legalistic doubts?

This is why I disagree with the western church judicial/legalistic perspective of salvation. Yes there is a judge and there is a law. But our salvation is about how we try to imitate Christ and how we have a relationship with God. It is about restoring with God's grace the likeness/image of God within us. Salvation is a process it is a relationship. (Relationships are processes, with different stages) Salvation is not a legal system, those aspects are incidental. If you're friends with God and you don't attempt to upset Him, He sees that and recognizes you. Unlike the goats.

Not putting an answer, because this question is clearly within the protestant realm of christianity. But issues like this highlight why viewing salvation as a legal system is strange to me and my understanding of having a relationship with God.

@wyrsa  That is why I scoped the Q with the Tag, reformed-theology. I, too, find this idea about the Law strange. I never heard this idea, that Christ perfectly kept the Law on our behalf, until a few years ago when looking at the Westminster Confession of Faith. To read that "The Christian's rule of life is the Law" shocked me. Though I'm not exactly asking about that - I confine my Q to what Christ did to enable this transference from Adam to himself.

What did JESUS DO, which (if he had not done) would mean we could never break free from being joined to Adam?
I'm answering this question separately as it was asked by OP, by way of clarification, in the comments to my previous answer to this question.  It's not that there's just one thing that Jesus did but a great number of things which are all interrelated.  This is why my previous answer began with "all of what Jesus has done would have to be the answer".
He lived a sinless life.  If he had not lived such a life we could never break free from Adam.
He condemned sin in the flesh. If the condemnation of sin had not been finalized we could never break free from Adam.
He both propitiated God's righteous wrath and expiated our sin with his life's blood.  If he had not poured out his blood we could never break free from Adam.
He pierced the veil that separates us from God.  If he had not opened a New and living way we could never break free from Adam.
He advocates with God for us. If he did not live forever to make intercession for us we could never break free from Adam.
He lives within us through the new birth. If the Spirit did not lust within us against the flesh we could never break free from Adam.
He made it so that salvation is through faith. If it were through works we could never break free from Adam.
He said and did everything the Father sent him for.  If he had disobeyed we could never break free from Adam.
And on and on and on.  Everything about him is redemptive. Everything about him leads to and enables salvation. Everything about him is worthy of all honor and glory and praise.  Everything about him is to be believed on, trusted entirely, and yearned after more than one's own life.  He is the break from Adam and the reconciliation back to God.

How do you know any of this is true? You seem to be making up your own interpretations of what is clearly written in the Bible. Jesus himself said that it was through works that we would be saved, ie keep the commandments and give away our possessions to the poor.

@SafeFastExpressive That isn’t correct—see John 6:29 for example: Jesus answered, “The work of God is this: to believe in the one he has sent. (that is, to believe in Jesus. That entire exchange is about faith not works).

Though as James points out in his epistle, saving faith produces works—it’s the whole idea of repentance.

@SafeFastExpressive And who did Jesus say that to? Was it to a person who was trying to demonstrate themselves as righteous through the law?  Absolute sinless perfection is required to get righteousness that way.

@SafeFastExpressive Luke 7:50: “Your faith has saved you.”

It is abundantly clear in Paul's explanation that the death of Christ is the means by which we are dead to the first humanity (being one with Christ in his death) and alive in the new humanity (being one with Christ in his resurrection) :

But not as the offence, so also is the free gift. For if through the offence of one many be dead, much more the grace of God, and the gift by grace, which is by one man, Jesus Christ, hath abounded unto many. And not as it was by one that sinned, so is the gift: for the judgment was by one to condemnation, but the free gift is of many offences unto justification. For if by one man's offence death reigned by one; much more they which receive abundance of grace and of the gift of righteousness shall reign in life by one, Jesus Christ.)


Therefore as by the offence of one judgment came upon all men to condemnation; even so by the righteousness of one the free gift came upon all men unto justification of life. For as by one man's disobedience many were made sinners, so by the obedience of one shall many be made righteous. Moreover the law entered, that the offence might abound. But where sin abounded, grace did much more abound: That as sin hath reigned unto death, even so might grace reign through righteousness unto eternal life by Jesus Christ our Lord. [Romans 5:12-21 KJV/TR]

This occurred when God 'made him to be sin for us' then Christ himself yielded up his life so that sin, itself, was eradicated in his death.
Thus not only were sins borne 'in his body on the tree' but also sin itself was destroyed through his death.
Thus, in resurrection there is a new humanity, Jesus Christ is the prototokos, the first token of a new creation.
Thus may Paul say 'I am crucified with Christ, nevertheless I live, yet not I, but Christ liveth in me'.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Jesus Christ is not a token but the living bread and the first born raised from the dead.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Prototokos is proto and tokos. In Scripture, tokos is used twice and twice only with the meaning usury. That  is to say it is the return on an investment. Thus the Prototokos is the first return on the investment God has made in Creation. Thus - the first token. First 'born' is incorrect as a translation as the context, scripturally, is financial investment, not generational. On emust follow how the Spirit uses words in scripture, otherwise one is conjecturing out of context.


OP: Is there anywhere in the entire Bible that states we have union with Christ through his obedience to the Law?


For as by one man's disobedience many were made sinners, so by the obedience of one shall many be made righteous. Rom 5:19

The "one man's disobedience" of course refers to Adam.  To what did Adam disobey?  He did not believe God.
To what did the One (Christ Jesus) be obedient?  Paul explains.

Moreover the [Mosaic] law entered, that the offence might abound. But where sin abounded, grace did much more abound: That as sin hath reigned unto death, even so might grace reign through righteousness unto eternal life by Jesus Christ our Lord.  Rom 5:20-21

"By" because of, through, as a result of Jesus Christ.

For he [God] hath made him [Christ] to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him. 2 Cor 5:21

The union with Christ, however, is not automatic.  Paul says "might".  We must believe by grace through faith.

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Eph 2:8

Lastly, it is important to understand the terms of the Mosaic Law and how it relates to us.

And it [Mosaic Law in totality] shall be our righteousness, if we observe to do all these commandments before the LORD our God, as he hath commanded us. Deut 6:25

No one could do that, except Christ.  So, now Paul again.

And be found in him, not having mine own righteousness, which is of the law, but that which is through the faith of Christ, the righteousness which is of God by faith: Phl 3:9

Not my righteousness, but Christ's righteousness.

OP: What enables anyone to be transferred from being united to Adam to Christ?

As mentioned, you are saved by grace through faith; as a gift from God.  God enables that.  We don't "save ourselves" initially or consequently.  That's many religions, but pure Christianity sticks to that gift (unearned) from God.
We understand that transferrence more in the physical sense at water baptism.

And that ye put on the new man, which after God is created in righteousness and true holiness. Eph 4:24

"Put on" is a verb in the aorist tense (the concept of the verb is considered without regard for past, present, or future time. There is no direct or clear English equivalent for this tense, though it is generally rendered as a simple past tense in most translations. BlueLetterBible reference).
When?  Water baptism.

For as many of you as have been baptized into Christ have put on Christ. Gal 3:27


And have put on the new man, which is renewed in knowledge after the image of him that created him: Col 3:10

To be sure, after this enablement, there is more, but that's the basics.
Hope that helps a bit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I think you confuse several elements:

How Christ became eligible as the head of a new humanity, i.e. what Christ did to enable this transference from Adam to himself.
How do we join the new humanity through Union with Christ.
Comparison of the old head and the new head (the topic of Romans 5:12-21 as well as 1 Cor 15:20-49).
The purpose of the law in the New Covenant (topic of WCF XIX:1-7, short commentary here).

How Jesus brought about a new humanity
First, let's talk about #1: what Christ did to enable this transference from Adam to himself.  I'm using a short essay by Brandon Crowe (who I believe is Reformed) titled Jesus Christ: The Last Adam which describes how Jesus "reverses the results of the curse" of Adam by

Jesus being the "Son of God in a more fundamental sense" (virginal conception) than Adam's being a natural son of God (natural birth).  So from the get go, Jesus already has more to give the new humanity.

Passing the test of sonship (by obedience to death on a tree) rather than Adam's failing the "probationary test" not to eat from the tree of knowledge of good and evil.  From the essay:

This was no arbitrary command but was a summary command that tested Adam’s entire love for God.

People joined with Adam have imperfect love, but Jesus has perfect love.  Love is the essential ingredient of the new humanity.  Believers who are joined with Christ can potentially have perfect love through being connected with our Head, the Vine.

Because Adam failed the test, he forfeit eternal life.  But because Jesus obeyed the demand of love to death on the cross, God granted Jesus (and those united with Him) eternal life.

Adam's kingdom is forfeited to Satan, the ruler of this world.  But for the new humanity,

The Son of Man is a new Adam, who reigns over a lasting kingdom.

By passing this obedience test, Satan's kingdom is now disarmed.  Believers are on a rescue mission to announce the existence of this new humanity (the "gospel"), so the citizens of the defeated world can ask God to be transferred to Jesus's lasting kingdom (which includes asking "forgiveness" and asking to be "reborn").  From the essay:

Jesus binds the strong man by his obedience, freeing those who are in bondage to the devil, and offering forgiveness of sins (Matt 12:22–32; Mark 3:22–30).



How we join the new humanity through Union with Christ
The essay above reframes salvation as inviting us to join the new humanity Christ has established.  This is the Recapitulation theory of atonement.
How do we join?  Through Union with Christ.  Please refer to Reformed John Piper's article What Is Union with Christ?.  Please note that in the article there is no mention that we become united with Christ through his obedience to the Law, but through being born again and through baptism, experienced through faith.  (The exact sequence of events depend on which Reformed tradition, Confessional vs. Baptist, but the elect will have all 3 eventually.)  If the link between Union with Christ and Christ's obedience to the Law is in the Bible, I'm pretty sure John Piper would have included it.
Instead, Jesus's obedience to death (described in the previous section) is articulated most clearly in Phil 2:8, part of Paul's description of how Jesus (though God) humbled himself.  As we have seen, this is a different kind of obedience than Jesus's perfect obedience to the Law.  It's Christ's obedience (out of love) to the Trinitarian God's will to save humanity through the Word's Incarnation dying on the cross.
Comparison of the two heads
Yes, of course we are justified by his blood (Rom 5:9-10 you quoted), but I'm going to argue that Rom 5:6-21 talks about one single act of Adam and one single act of Jesus rather than multiple acts of obeying the Law.  Rom 5:6-11 doesn't talk about Jesus's obedience to the Law but about Jesus's obedience to God's will to prove His Father's love for us (v. 8).  The next passage (Rom 5:12-21) is a series of comparison of the two heads and their two acts:



Adam
Jesus




sin and death entered the world through Adam (v. 12)
grace comes to the world through Jesus, "the gift" (v. 15)


by one man's trespass many died
through the gift of one man many are justified (v. 15-16)


from Adam death reigns
from Christ life reigns (v. 17)


one trespass result in condemnation for everyone
one righteous act result in life for everyone (v. 18)


through one man's disobedience many were made sinners
through one man's obedience many will be made righteous (v. 19)


etc.




Your Evangelical Times article also talks about this single act obedience, which I would interpret as referring to v. 8 (obedience to death on the cross):

According to Romans 5, however, humans are saved through the obedience of someone else (Christ), having also been condemned through the disobedience of someone else (Adam).

Purpose of the law in the new kingdom
Then the article has the sentence referring to legalism, which by definition is about obedience to the Law.  I think this is a separate concern.  Let's bring WCF 19 into the picture.  Reading through the whole chapter it is obvious that the Law still has a role for us.  WCF 19.6 is emphatic that

Although true believers be not under the law as a covenant of works ... yet is it of great use to them ... as a rule of life, informing them of the will of God and their duty, ...

But that chapter does not have any connection with the New Humanity, nor with Union with Christ, nor with Christ's obedience to his mission to die on the cross.  (Although as imitators of Christ, we too, are invited to undertake a VOLUNTARY mission of love.)  This is talking about how we need to do our best to obey the law (which Paul pronounced is holy and good, Rom 7:12).  We receive help by being yoked with Jesus (our new head) while remaining sinners, not to earn our justification but as a grateful response to our new Head who is walking alongside us in our walk of purification, yoked with us in solidarity, to encourage us and to empower us through the vine.
Mission of love and obeying the law are two separate tracks; one is voluntary out of love (fruit of the Holy Spirit), the other is moral duty (obeying our conscience).  In the Reformed tradition, neither are necessary for justification, but are expected from those already "transferred" from the old head Adam to the new head Christ.
Conclusion
As a follow up you asked:

What did JESUS DO, which (if he had not done) would mean we could never break free from being joined to Adam?

Answer: What Jesus did is: established the new humanity with Himself as the head through His incarnation and death on the cross (see my first section).  Secondly, he offered a way for us to be part of the new humanity through union with Him.  We accept that offer through being born again, etc.  By being united with Christ, we are safe from all attacks of Satan, Adam's inheritance. Without this new humanity, we "could never break free".

"The transfer is through faith and baptism."  Does this, then, equal the new birth?

@MikeBorden As you and I know, new birth is implied, but thanks for the feedback, I have made my answer more explicit.  At any rate, the purpose of the answer is not to dig deep into the debate of baptismal regeneration vs. credobaptism, but to answer the specific concern in the OP related to Reformed understanding of Union with Christ.

Thank you for the answer, which shows that "Christ's obedience here is not to the law".  Just to keep things on track - I'm asking what Christ did to enable this transference from Adam to himself. The Q is not about what we do, or how Adam compares with Christ as 'head', or what follows after Christ enables this transference to take place.

@Anne I have added a new section to answer your question "what Christ did to enable this transference from Adam to himself" in terms of Christ's creating a new humanity that we can join.  I also reorganized the remaining answer.  Please let me know if there is more improvement to make.

I appreciate how much time, research and effort goes into your answers (which are never scant or wandering). You must answer as you believe, and not as how the OP might desire! All I would say is, look at the comment I left under Mike Borden's answer.

@Anne I made a final edit to make the answer more coherent, esp. that Rom 5:12-21 is also about that obedience to death, not obedience to the law.  It's kind of obvious from the text, don't you think?

@Anne OK, I added a conclusion based on your comment to Mike Borden's answer.

That change to the opening sentence in the 'Comparison' section is most helpful, as is your new conclusion. And, yes, it's obvious from the text that this is about Christ's obedience unto death on the cross.

There is no transfer.
Once in Adam, always in Adam. To be "in Adam" means to be a descendant. It means having been literally in his body in the form of a soul, like Levi is said to have been in Abraham.
To be "in Christ" means to have a portion of the Holy Spirit life living in you.

Can one be both in Adam and in Christ ultimately?

Yes. Every one who was in Adam, will ultimately be made alive in Christ. Most only at the white throne judgement; the elect members of the bride of Christ during their lifetimes.

Answers to questions on this site have to submit Christian, biblical evidence. Otherwise those three sentences are nothing but personal opinion - which this site states will not do.  In view of your comment in response to another one, can you include in your answer biblical evidence that still sticks to the question?

Hey while your answer can have personal opinions, if it isn't backed by anything at all other then faith or personal conviction... then it is not an appropriate answer. You have some vague loosely connected points, but some kind of article or something would make this a better answer.
